# Are there any good OpenGL ES 2.0 examples for the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

Starting with the iPhone 3G S, OpenGL ES 2.0 has been supported on iOS devices.  However, I can't find much in the way of sample code for OpenGL ES 2.0 aimed at the iPhone, or even some generic examples.  Where can I find sample code or tutorials about OpenGL ES 2.0 for the iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a very basic example, the OpenGL ES Application template in the latest iOS SDK creates a basic application with two rendering paths, one OpenGL ES 1.1-based, the other using OpenGL ES 2.0.

Aside from that, I recommend watching the [WWDC 2010 video](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/) session 417 - "OpenGL ES Shading and Advanced Rendering" for some examples of OpenGL ES 2.0 shaders on the iPhone.  The book "[iPhone 3D Programming](http://iphone-3d-programming.labs.oreilly.com/)" by Philip Rideout walks you through the use of OpenGL ES 2.0 shaders in an iPhone application.

Finally, I believe that "[OpenGL Shading Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321197895)" by Randi Rost is still considered the definitive reference for the shaders used in OpenGL ES 2.0.